# Unable to send data to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am starting out building some very simple apps and I think I have a handle on how to create the basics over in android studio. What I can't figure out for the life of me is why I cannot send data to my firebase realtime database.

This is a very simple app that i've tried to make it work with currently (as i couldnt figure it out in the more fleshed out one) - simply with one button that is supposed to send "Hello, World!"

```
package com.example.clean_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference root = db.getReference();
    private Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                root.setValue("Hello, World!");
                Log.i("test","test");
            }
        });



        
    }




}
```

Where the heck am I going wrong? I can see the button clicks in Logcat so that works - and I cant seem to find any errors, so its likely something very obvious. If it matters, Mac air w/ M1, attempted to make this connection with a VDA as well as a proper android device.

Thanks ahead of time and apologies for the likely very stupid question :D

Comment: Also - evidently this might be something in the Gradle config too - but I followed that directly from the Firebase gui and am not using BOM currently to make it simpler to troubleshoot :) I'll post those if someone thinks that is where the issue might be

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() operation to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: Working on this now

Answer (score 0):

Try refer to child like

```java
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                root.child("NewTable").setValue("Hello, World!");
                Log.i("test","test");
            }
        });
```